# How can I change the python path being used in R?

Tags: python, r

I am struggling to use python libraries in my R project. I think it is because I am installing the packages using the terminal in my project but the python path in the terminal doesn't match the path in my console.

here is what I get when I run `which python` in terminal:

```
/Users/<username>/anaconda2/bin/python
```

here is what I get when I run `system("which python")` in console:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

I tried writing `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("/Users/<username>/anaconda2/bin/python", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))` but that didn't change the path I got.

How can I change the python path I use in my console so that it matches the one I'm using in my terminal?

On Mac btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in a Linux platform. 
you can add soft-links. That way it will point to a single source.

Additionally i would recommend using a environment(eg.conda). that way it will always be localized to your project.

Comment: thanks for the input! I am on Mac and ill look into using conda

Comment: conda environment was giving errors when trying to run through some python scripts. honestly I am trying to go through this tutorial here https://github.com/armbrustlab/popcycle/wiki/SeaFlow-data-analysis-tutorial. and i am struggling to do it correctly because in R I get errors about how seaflow cannot be used.